# Importing 2 lists of dictionaries and nesting key/value pairs in python

Tags: python, json

I have 2 jsons that are lists of dictionaries which I'd like to use to create a 3rd json in python.

First json is **last_names.json**

```
[{
    "lastnameID": "1",
    "name": "Doe"
}, {
    "lastnameID": "2",
    "name": "Smith"
}]
```

Second json is **first_names.json**

```
[{
    "firstnameID": "1",
    "name": "John",
    "lastnameID": "1"
}, {
    "firstnameID": "2",
    "name": "Jane",
    "lastnameID": "1"
}, {
    "firstnameID": "3",
    "name": "Bob",
    "lastnameID": "2"
}, {
    "firstnameID": "4",
    "name": "Mary",
    "lastnameID": "2"
}]
```

I'd like my output to be this **output.json**

```
[{
    "lastnameID": "1",
    "name": "Doe",
    "first names": [{
        "firstnameID": "1",
        "name": "John"
    }, {
        "firstnameID": "2",
        "name": "Jane"
    }]
}, {
    "lastnameID": "2",
    "name": "Smith",
    "first names": [{
        "firstnameID": "3",
        "name": "Bob"
    }, {
        "firstnameID": "4",
        "name": "Mary"
    }]
}]
```

How can I do this on python 3?

I tried below, but there has to be a better way than this

```
import json

finaljson = []
with open('first_names.json', 'r') as f:
    firstnames = json.load(f)
with open('last_names.json', 'r') as f:
    lastnames = json.load(f)
for i in range (0, len (lastnames)):
    firstnamelist = []
    lastnameID = lastnames[i]['lastnameID']
    lastname = lastnames[i]['name']
    for i in range (0, len (firstnames))
        if firstnames[i]['lastnameID'] == lastnameID:
            firstname = firstnames[i]['name']
            firstnameID = firstnames[i]['firstnameID']
            firstnamelist.append("firstnameID":firstnameID,"name":firstname)
    finaljson.append({"lastnameID":lastnameID,"name":lastname,"firstnames":firstnamelist})
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: load them both into memory separately, then write the logic to combine them into the format you want.

Comment: @JoshKarpel I added what I've tried into my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Within Dictionary**

```
for first_ in first:
    first_['first names'] = [{x:y for x, y in second_.items() if x == 'firstnameID' or x == 'name'} 
                             for second_ in second if second_['lastnameID'] == first_['lastnameID']]

print (first)
```

Please see the following result:

```
[{'lastnameID': '1', 'name': 'Doe', 
      'first names': [{'firstnameID': '1', 'name': 'John'}, 
                      {'firstnameID': '2', 'name': 'Jane'}]}, 
 {'lastnameID': '2', 'name': 'Smith', 
      'first names': [{'firstnameID': '3', 'name': 'Bob'}, 
                      {'firstnameID': '4', 'name': 'Mary'}]}]
```

Comment: I tried that, I assume first is the first_names.json and second is the last_names.json.  I tried your code but got a different json structure.

Comment: @dne202 I see. I think I changed first and second. Please change your data between first and second. It will give the exact output what you want. I am sorry that I can't change in myself because i am in outside.

Comment: @dne202 great! Please select the answer if it solves your question. and vote up please